# Multiple pattern replacement rule in Mathematica

Tags: replacement

I am trying to replace the following expression with the definition $A[m,n]=\frac{1}{k^ml^n}$. The expression is $W=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{kl}$. So it should give $A[1,0]+A[1,1]$. So I need two replacement condition. But I do not know how to give multiple replacement in mathematica. I tried

```
W= 1/k+1/(k*l) /. {k^a_*l^b_-> A[-a,-b]}, {k^a_ -> A[-a,0]}
```

But it is not recognizing the second replacement rule

Comment: think you had an error in the symbols have fixed this to match the answer

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[a,b,L,k];
W=1/k+1/(k*L);
```

You can do

```
W /. k^a_*L^b_ -> A[-a, -b] /. k^a_ -> A[-a, 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
W/. k^a_*L^b_->A[-a,-b]/.Power[k,a_]->A[-a,0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do not add `{..},{..}` around patterns.